# Matrix transposition and invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

The following question is a question in my midterm, I could not develop any simpler forms of $AA^T = kI$.

> Let $A_{n\times n}$ verify the expression $AA^T=kI_{n\times n}$, $k\in R^{+}$.
>
> a) Show that $A$ is invertible and find $A^{-1}$.
>
> b) Calculate $A^{-1}(A^{-1})^T$.

Comment: **Hint:**

a) You can use the fact that $\det(A) = \det(A^T)$  and a matrix $B$ is invertible iff $\det(B) \neq 0.$  

In order to find $A^{-1}$, combine the facts that $AA^{-1} = I$ and $AA^T = k I.$

For b) I think you have enough information from a).

Comment: $AA^t=kI$, divide both sides by $k$.

Comment: Are you still there, Ahmed?

Answer (score 0):

Since $AA^T=kI,$ we can have $A(\frac{1}{k}A^T)=I,$ so $A$ is invertible with $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{k}A^T.$

Then the rest is direct computation:
$$A^{-1}(A^{-1})^T=\frac{1}{k}A^T(\frac{1}{k}A^T)^T=\frac{1}{k^2}A^TA=\frac{1}{k^2}\cdot kI=\frac{1}{k}I.$$

Comment: $A$ is invertible by virtue of $\det (AA^\top)=k^n\Rightarrow\det(A)=k^{n/2}\ne 0$, as $k>0$.